How to toggle Tagify Inputs Between Editable and Non-Editable Modes
I know there are examples, but I don't seem to be smart enough to figure out what to do.
I'm working on a JavaScript application where users can create notes with tags. I'm using the Tagify library to enhance the tag input functionality.
I'm initializing the Tagify input as follows:
const tagInput = document.querySelector('.note-tags');
const tagify = new Tagify(tagInput, {
    whitelist: ['example-tag-1', 'example-tag-2', 'example-tag-3'],
    enforceWhitelist: false,
    dropdown: {
        position: 'input',
        enabled: 0 // Always show suggestions
    }
});
tagify.addTags(['example-tag-1', 'example-tag-2']);

I need to toggle this Tagify input between:

Editable mode: Users can add/remove tags.
Non-editable mode: Users cannot modify the tags.

Here’s my attempt to toggle the editable state:
function setTagifyEditMode(editable) {
    const tagifyElement = document.querySelector("[class^='tagify']");
    if (editable) {
        tagifyElement.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
        tagify.settings.readonly = false;
    } else {
        tagifyElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
        tagify.settings.readonly = true;
    }

    tagify.DOM.input.readOnly = !editable;

    // Updating the settings
    tagify.update();
}

// Example usage
setTagifyEditMode(false); // Making the Tagify input non-editable

Despite attempting the changes above, the Tagify input remains editable even in non-editable mode. How can I correctly toggle the Tagify input between editable and non-editable states?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Toggle Tagify Input Editable State</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/4.0.0/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .tagify__input--readonly .tagify__tag {
            pointer-events: none; /* Disable interaction */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="note-tags">Tags:</label>
        <input name="tags" class="note-tags" placeholder="Add tags" value="example-tag-1,example-tag-2">
    </div>
    <button onclick="setTagifyEditMode(true)">Enable Editing</button>
    <button onclick="setTagifyEditMode(false)">Disable Editing</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/4.0.0/tagify.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const tagInput = document.querySelector('.note-tags');
            const tagify = new Tagify(tagInput, {
                whitelist: ['example-tag-1', 'example-tag-2', 'example-tag-3'],
                enforceWhitelist: false,
                dropdown: {
                    position: 'input',
                    enabled: 0 // Always show suggestions
                }
            });
            tagify.addTags(['example-tag-1', 'example-tag-2']);

            window.setTagifyEditMode = function(editable) {
                const tagifyElement = document.querySelector("[class^='tagify']");
                if (editable) {
                    console.log(`editable: ${editable}`);
                    //tagifyElement.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
                    //tagify.settings.readonly = false;
                    console.log("running setReadonly('remove'");
                    tagifyElement.setReadonly('remove', 'readonly');
                    tagify.setReadonly('remove', 'readonly');
                } else {
                    console.log(`editable: ${editable}`);
                    //tagifyElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
                    //tagify.settings.readonly = true;
                    tagify.setReadonly('set', 'readonly');
                }
                tagify.DOM.input.readOnly = !editable;
                tagify.update();
            };

            // Initially set the Tagify input as non-editable
            setTagifyEditMode(false);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>




In your setTagifyEditMode function you may change the editTags setting to false in order to disallow editing:
tagify.editTags = false

You can also call either tagify.setReadonly(STATE) (or tagify.setContentEditable) but this will not allow users to add or remove tags.
(Note that STATE is a Boolean)
